# Implementing SUMIF() function from Excel to SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, sum, sumifs

Lately, I have been learning how to use SQL in order to process data. Normally, I would use Python for that purpose, but SQL is required for the classes and I still very much struggle with using it comfortably in more complicated scenarios.

What I want to achieve is the same result as in the following screenshot in Excel:

[Behaviour in Excel, that I want to implement in SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avrVo.png)

The formula I used in Excel:

```
=SUMIF(B$2:B2;B2;C$2:C2)
```

Sample of the table:

```
> select * from orders limit 5;
+------------+---------------+---------+
| ID         | clientID      | tonnage |
+------------+---------------+---------+
| 2005-01-01 | 872-13-44-365 |      10 |
| 2005-01-04 | 369-43-03-176 |       2 |
| 2005-01-05 | 408-24-90-350 |       2 |
| 2005-01-10 | 944-16-93-033 |       5 |
| 2005-01-11 | 645-32-78-780 |      14 |
+------------+---------------+---------+
```

The implementation is supposed to return similar results as following `group by` query:

```
select
    orders.clientID as ID,
    sum(orders.tonnage) as Tonnage
from orders
group by orders.clientID;
```

That is, return how much each client have purchased, but at the same I want it to return each step of the addition as separate record.

For an instance:

Client A bought 350 in the first order and then 231 in the second one.
 In such case the query would return something like this:

```
client A - 350 - 350 // first order
client A - 281 - 581 // second order
```

[Example, how it would look like in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRhez.png)

I have already tried to use something like:

```
select
    orders.clientID as ID,
    sum(case when orders.clientID = <ID> then orders.tonnage end)
from orders;
```

But got stuck quickly, since I would need to somehow dynamically change this `<ID>` and store it's value in some kind of temporary variable and I can't really figure out how to implement such thing in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window function for running sum.

In your case, use like this

```sql
select id, clientID, sum(tonnage) over (partition by clientID order by id) tonnageRunning
from   orders
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=13a8c2d46b5ac22c5c120ac937bd6e7a

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for.